# youtube player api z-index problem

Tags: youtube-api

i am using player api for showing you tube videos i have a similar problem asked before also by someone that the player is coming over the popup screen no matter how much i set the z-index of the popup it is not coming up how to solve this i have tried the same method that was answered previously but that is not working for me in my case i am having problem with IE

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may consider setting 'wmode' to 'transparent' when embedding the SWF player.

var params = { allowScriptAccess: "always", **'wmode' : 'opaque'**}

Tested in Firefox, Chrome 7. and Safari !

Comment: Shouldn't `'wmode': 'opaque'` work too?  It has better performance in some browsers.